# static resources OK on local host, not found on remote server

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, thymeleaf

I've spring boot app with some static resources serving through thymeleaf as follows

#### Head section

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <title>Home | Connect In</title>

    <!-- Vendor CSS -->
        <link th:href="@{/vendors/bower_components/animate.css/animate.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link th:href="@{/vendors/bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link th:href="@{/vendors/bower_components/material-design-iconic-font/dist/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css}"
              rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link th:href="@{/vendors/bower_components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link th:href="@{/vendors/bower_components/lightgallery/dist/css/lightgallery.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link th:href="@{/css/app_1.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link th:href="@{/css/app_2.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
```

#### At end of page

```
<!-- Javascript Libraries -->
        <script th:src="@{/vendors/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/vendors/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script th:src="@{/vendors/bower_components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/vendors/bower_components/Waves/dist/waves.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/vendors/bootstrap-growl/bootstrap-growl.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/vendors/bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/vendors/bower_components/lightgallery/dist/js/lightgallery-all.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/vendors/bower_components/autosize/dist/autosize.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Placeholder for IE9 -->
        <!--[if IE 9 ]>
            <script th:src="@{/vendors/bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <script th:src="@{/js/app.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this app works fine on local host server environment, means all resources are well served, but when I deploy the app on [openshift](http://boot-supremes.rhcloud.com/), I get errors which can be seen in this snippet

[image: GET not found 404 error]

don't know how can I fix this, any recommendation and suggestion is strongly welcome..

Comment: __Important__ : there is not Spring Security in the app and not any custom config, all configurations are default!!

Comment: Without a configuration for serving static resources it's hard to help you.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin any link, suggestion or other sort of help please?

Comment: Who and how is serving files from the `/vendors/`  directory? Are these files inside of `src/main/resources` directory?

Comment: @SlavaSemushin First of all thank you for your time and sorry for late reply, yes these files are inside of `src/main/resources directory`, but I've solved the issue by serving those files from __cdn__!

Answer (score 0):

by using **cdn** it solved the issues, you can change

#### Head section

```
<!-- Vendor CSS -->
        <link th:href="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/animate.css-3.5.2/animate.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link th:href="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/sweetalert-1.1.2/dist/sweetalert.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link th:href="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/material-design-iconic-font-2.2.0/dist/css/material-design-iconic-font.css}"
              rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link th:href="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin-3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link th:href="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/lightgallery-1.3.9/dist/css/lightgallery.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

#### At end section

```
<!-- Javascript Libraries -->
        <script th:src="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/jquery-3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script th:src="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin-3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/waves-0.7.5/dist/waves.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-growl/1.0.6/bootstrap-growl.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/sweetalert-1.0.1/dist/sweetalert.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/lightgallery-1.3.9/dist/js/lightgallery.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script th:src="@{https://bowercdn.net/c/autosize-3.0.21/dist/autosize.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hence the issues are solved...

Thank you.

Comment: If you're using external URLs then you can replace `th:src` by `src`. This also makes a prototype use these urls.